# Immutable Items in RecyclerView

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

Is it any way to on start of `Activity` or `Fragment` with `RecyclerView` add in it elements, that will be unavailable for changes throughout the entire lifecycle of the this list?

For example:

```
class CategoryRecyclerAdapter(
    private val onItemLongClickListener: (Category) -> Unit = { },
    private val onItemClickListener: (Category) -> Unit = { }
) : Adapter<CategoryRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private val items: MutableList<Category> = mutableListOf()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int,
    ): CategoryRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val binding =
            CategoryItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CategoryRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (items.isNotEmpty()) {
            holder.bind(items[position])
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

    inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: CategoryItemBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(item: Category) {
            binding.root.setOnLongClickListener {
                onItemLongClickListener(item)
                true
            }
            binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                onItemClickListener(item)
            }
            binding.nameTextView.text = item.name
        }
    }

    fun set(elements: List<Category>) {
        val currentSize = this.items.size
        this.items.clear()
        this.items.addAll(elements)
        this.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, currentSize)
        this.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, elements.size)
    }
}
```

I need to add one element to the beginning and another to the end of the list so that they always remain the first and last elements of the list, no matter how many times other elements are added or removed.

Comment: Add the first and last element as header and footer

Comment: @BincyBaby But I need them to scroll with the rest of the elements as if they are part of a list

Comment: header and footer will scroll with the recycler view. Also you can consider @ardiien's answer

Answer (score 0):

Just prefill your list with "blank" data and do whatever you want for that item in the `onBindViewHolder` or create a separate `ViewHolder` in `onCreateViewHolder` with unchangeable data.

There are tons of tutorials on "How to use RecyclerView with several ViewHolder types". Also, I recommend using Jetpack Compose or at least Epoxy from Airbnb.